# Input element height is not changed

Tags: html, css, input

I want a font size of 13px in the `<input>`, but the height of the input is 16px. Can I get any information about this?

```css
input {
    padding : 13px 12px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    margin-top : 4px;
    font-size : 13px;
    line-height : 1;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

This is what the box model in the dev tools shows:

[image: Content box is 152 × 16 pixels. Padding is 13 pixels at top and bottom, 12 pixels at left and right. Border is 1 pixel. Margin is 4 pixels at the top.]

Comment: set height 13px

Comment: I need to set the height of input through font-size and line-height

Answer (score 0):

Just try this i hope it will help..

```
input {
    padding : 13px 12px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    margin-top : 4px;
    font-size : 13px;
    line-height : 1;
    height:13px;
    }
```

Comment: thank you but I need to set the height of input through font-size and line-height